# How to get Device UDID without XCode and without downloading any profile in 2020

Tags: ios, udid

What is the best way/ right way to get the device's `UDID`? Without having `XCode` or without downloading any profile.
I've tried get.udid.io - It isn't working for my iPad, though worked for iPhone.
I've tried whatsmyudid.com - It downloads a profile which is not verified- Can't ask my client to download such profiles.
Moreover, what is the official way of knowing my device's UDID?

Comment: did you tried iTunes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get device UDID by connecting it to Mac and run following command on terminal.

```
instruments -s devices
```

`instruments` is deprecated now use `rcrun`

```
xcrun xctrace list devices
```

It will display all devices names (and simulators) along with UDID.

Comment: Good one! Butt... tool 'xctrace' requires Xcode